# Connecting to PostGIS from MapInfo

Tags: postgis, mapinfo

I'm using MapInfo 15.2 64-bit and I am trying to connect a PostGIS database to display it in MapInfo. I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 with PostGIS 2.2.2. I have seen all kind of suggestions on different forums recommending to use EasyLoader to create a map catalog to be able to make the DB tables mappable.

If I connect to the DBMS using directly OPEN DBMS function, I am able to view the tables within a browser, as they do not have a map catalog created yet, but the main important thing is that I am able to connect to the database. OPEN DBMS function recognizes the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(ANSI) driver.

If I try to connect to the database using EasyLoader, the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(ANSI) driver doesn't show up as an option to create a new data source.

Is there an software incompatibility that doesn't allow EasyLoader to view the PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(ANSI) driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a question of what bit-type your ODBC driver has been created as.

MapInfo Pro 15.2 is 64-bit as you write yourself.

EasyLoader is however still a 32-bit application so it does require a 32-bit ODBC driver to work.

There is a 64-bit version of EasyLoader on the way. It is due before summer 2016.

Comment: I have installed the 32-bit ODBC driver through Stack Builder in PostgreSQL, and now the EasyLoader does recognize the driver. Thank you very much for your help.